# Tkinter use place for button in frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to position my buttons in my tkinter frame. I wanted to use the .place method to position my buttons in the frame because I think it is easier than grid(). My problem is that when I do that my window has just its minimal size and I see no buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    

    def __init__(self):

        print("Building App")
        
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root, padx= 300, pady= 300)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Button1", height=4, width=20)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Button2", height=4, width=20)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Button3", height=4, width=20)

        self.button1.place(x=200, y= 200)
        self.button2.place(x=200, y= 250)

        self.button3.grid(column=1,row=1)

        self.frame.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

a = App()
```

When I add a button with grid() then I see all my buttons. Can someone explain me why the program / the buttons is / are behaving like that?

Comment: Why is it that you believe it's easier than `grid`?  `place` is notoriously more difficult to create a responsive GUI with, especially when you start running the script on computers with different display settings, resolutions, screen sizes etc.

Comment: If creating a vertical or  horizontal grouping of buttons, `pack` is easier than either `grid` or `place`, and makes it much easier to create a responsive UI than using `place`.

Comment: @BryanOakley (at)Rory I am struggling with placing my widgets inside the grids because I did not get it done to place them where I want. Is it possible to change the amount of collumns and rows and their sizes? Or can I put more than one widget on one field? I also had the problem that a label pushed a button away even if it was not interfeering with it.

Comment: Yes, you have complete control over how many rows and columns, and the sizes of the rows and columns.

Comment: If you have not seen [this tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-pack/) on the `pack` geometry manager then it is probably worth reading.  They also have [this one](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/) for `grid` if you are interested.  `place` is certainly the easiest to understand on the surface but it can quickly lead to difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `place` method for the buttons doesn't prompt the frame to grow to a size where you can actually see the buttons. So you can manually add `width` and `height` arguments to the frame to force it to grow. The buttons were there all along, but the frame was too small to show them!

```py
self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=800, height=800, padx= 300, pady= 300)
```